# How do I work with PHP and JavaScript together

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on a mini project on PHP. I'm using a div tag (with id="words") for displaying the words to be typed. For time being I've used javascript for initializing *words*  with a particular string of text, using a variable *str*.
I've saved the code for initialization in script.js along with all the other javascript code needed for the site and have linked it to the main PHP page.
Now if I want to fetch the string of text from the database, I'll have to use PHP. So how do I use PHP to fetch the data and store it in the *str* variable for the initialization function to do it's work.

PS:
*str* variable is declared in the script.js file.

Comment: Read something about ajax.

Comment: This is a very simple question which can be solved with Google. If you are having specific problems with some code that isn't working, come back and ask, otherwise I'd suggest a search.

Comment: Well if it's a one-time loading into a script file of a PHP variable, AJAX is not necessary. @MartinHeralecký Read something JSON

Comment: Dynamic javascript variables. Hidden form elements printed by PHP. Ajax.

Comment: @Dharmang he wants the variables to be dynamic?

Comment: Yaa JSON is good option then.

Comment: This sounds more like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious comments and time. This was my first question on stackoverflow. I also am a newbie in php and javascript. Will learn ajax and json now... :)